# Does address.transfer() method prevents underflow/overflow?

Tags: solidity

I'm not sure if this is a legit concern but I would still want to know. If anyone can enlighten me. I know that the `address.transfer()` method is mostly viewed as the safest way to send eth within the contract so this is what I mostly use that is why I want to know if it can prevent an underflow or an overflow even though it is highly unlikely that someone can acquire that much ether [Please refer to the note as well] to cause an overflow.

> Note that there is not enough ETH in existence to cause an overflow, the total amount of wei fits well within 256 bits

Comment: Note that there is not enough ETH in existence to cause an overflow, the total amount of wei fits well within 256 bits

Comment: Right, I am aware of that as well. Please let me include this bit to my question and rephrase this part `even though it is highly unlikely that someone can acquire that much ether to cause an overflow.` Thank you

Comment: Interesting question. Hope this gets more answers. +1 from me

Answer (score 2):

The [`address.transfer()`](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=transfer#address-related) method will prevent any unintended underflow from an account. It will cause a `revert` in these situations, and stop the entire transaction from occurring.

Answer (score 1):

The total ether supply is 102 million and 1 ether equals 10^18 wei. That amounts to about total wei supply 10^26 wei which fits into 87 bits (take the binary logarithm of total wei supply). There shouldn't be any overflow problem with the `amount` parameter because it is a uint256.

Comment: Yes, just as @Tjaden Hess♦ already said and I've also added his note to the question.